# how to make the WCF server asynchronous?

Tags: .net, wcf

Service:

```
public class Service:IContracts
{
    private const string baseLocation = "E:\\";
    private FileStream _stream;
    private byte[] _buffer;
    public double Add(double x, double y) 【2】
    {
        return x + y;
    }

    public IAsyncResult BeginAsy(string fileName, AsyncCallback userCallback, object stateObject)【1】
    {
         this._stream = new FileStream(baseLocation + fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
         this._buffer = new byte[this._stream.Length];
         return this._stream.BeginRead(this._buffer, 0, this._buffer.Length, userCallback, stateObject);
    }

    public string EndAsy(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        this._stream.EndRead(ar);
        this._stream.Close();
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(this._buffer);
     }
}
```

Client:  an asynchronous call.

```
   proxy.BeginAsy("test.txt", asy =>   //'test.txt' is a large file 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(proxy.EndAsy(asy));
        }, null);
 Console.WriteLine(proxy.Add(1.0, 1.0));
```

the interface 'IService' and 'host' of the code is absolutely correct! will not Post,
why the code【2】 be excuted after code【1】 is completed?the server is asynchronous.?if not,The WCF server asynchronously is how to use?
I Hope that the code【1】 does not affect the execution of code【2】，the code【2】 can be excuted when code【1】 is executing。

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @user1577227: What exactly are you trying to achieve? In your example, both the client and the server use an asynchronous pattern? Is the client or the server supposed to be asynchronous? And what for? (The solution depends on these answers.)

Comment: Hope that the code【1】 does not affect the execution of code【2】，the code【2】 can be excuted when code【1】 is executing。

Comment: Without asynch client does it work?

Comment: the client is already an asynchronous call.

Comment: What part of WithOUT is not clear.